# Show the checked values from the first page in the second page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having the scenario where i have to select the cool drinks from multiple accordians and finally check the tin size in the first page,
**Example:** cool drinks -> Pepsi -> tin -> small tin(this is checked)
I want to display these selected and checked values in second page.
My code is as follows:

page1.html: http://jsfiddle.net/Ft34c/1/

This is my page2

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <!-- Display page1 selected values here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: I'd recommend storing your checked items in a cookie or localStorage. Then you can reference it on your next page.

Comment: It looks like you're submitting a form; the values should be  available server-side in the form POST variables.

Comment: Hi @CameronTinker, thanks for the suggestion. Please recommend me the link on how to work on the cookies.

Comment: @DigitalChris, i am not storing the values in the server side for now. Just to show the demo, i am using it.

Comment: You can make use of query strings on page2 and grab those using javascript. Not an ideal solution, but will do the job

Comment: If you are talking about multiple pages, you will have to do backflips without a server. Cookies have a server context. Localstorage has a server context.

Comment: Thanks @asprin, can you give me some references.

Comment: When checked any item that value store in hidden field of form then on submit you will get in post data that particular hidden field variable